# How can I programatically display the context menu for a file?

Tags: c#, .net

In a C# program I would like to display the context menu for a file.

For example: If the user clicked on the files name in my program, I would like to display the actual right click menu. By actual, I mean, the system context menu. I don't need programmatic access to the contents. I just need to display it.

Any ideas to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

> display the actual right click menu...the system context menu.

Can't be done from an exe to pull in a control from a win32 exe as such. One has to write their own context menu with the same look and feel.

---

In WPF you can add a `ContextMenu` to the list of files which opens up on a click event.

```
 <ListBox Name="myFileListBox">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu>
             <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click"/>
         </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>

    <ListBoxItem>File.txt</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>test.txt</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Roland.Txt</ListBoxItem>   
</ListBox>
```